# Map parts of dataframes and add new column-values using values from both

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes of different length.

Dataframe A is like this:

```
time_A   | Column_2 | Column_3
00:00:00 |   Type A |   ...
  ...    |   ...    |   ...
23:55:00 |   Type A |   ...
00:00:00 |   Type B |   ...
  ...    |   ...    |   ...
23:55:00 |   Type B |   ...
00:00:00 |   Type C |   ...
  ...    |   ...    |   ...
23:55:00 |   Type C |   ...
```

The time_A is of *string* type, and it contains less than 1000 rows.

Dataframe B is like this:

```
time_B           | Column_4 | Column_5
12/04/2019 00:00 |   abc    |   ...
12/04/2019 00:00 |   def    |   ...
  ...            |   ...    |   ...
12/04/2019 23:55 |   ghi    |   ...
12/04/2019 23:55 |   klm    |   ...
```

The time_B is of *string* type as well, and it contains around 200000 rows.

Now I have a range of time as datetime objects. Let's say

`[datetime.time(11, 0), datetime.time(20, 30)]`

What I want is to add a new column (Column_6) for all the rows that have time_B inside the above range.

The value of the individual Column_6 cells is taken of something like the below:

`for each_cell_with_time_B_inside_range:
     current_time = current_time_B
     df_B.["Column_6"] = each_Column_3_cell_with_current_time / sum(Column_3_of_type_x) * funct(each_Column_3_cell)`

or else with an example:

```
if total_2025_typeC = 100       --> we added all type C column_3 for 20:25:00
and current_column_3 = 20       --> the only value for type C 20:25:00 is 20
then column_6 = (20/100) * formula(20)
```

So far I have used:

```
newdf_index = df_B.index[(df_B["time_B"] >= range[0]) & (df_B["time_B"] <= range[1])].tolist()
```

,to get the row indexes from df_B for which I will add the new values to the new column. I have also played with loc, iloc, strftime, strptime, and tons of combinations that got me close but failed for so many reasons that I can't really write down.

My brain is fried by this time. Any help would be appreciated.

Maybe something like:

```
df_B.loc[df_B.index[indexes_where_time_B_is_within_range], "Column_6"] = ???
```

Comment: Just to clearify: `[datetime.time(11, 0), datetime.time(20, 30)]` means from 11:00:00 to 20:30:00?

Comment: @QuangHoang yes.

Comment: I still don't understand how these two go together `total_2025_typeC = 100 --> we add all type C for 20:25:00` and `current_column_3 = 20  --> the only value for type C 20:25:00`. If all Type C 20:25 add up to 100, then how come 20 is the only value?

Comment: That was my bad. What I meant was, 100 is the total for the range `[datetime.time(11, 0), datetime.time(20, 30)]` and since `20:25:00` is inside that range then the total that should be used is 100.